# Getting error "Failed to start Artifactory service" after Artifactory installation

Tags: service, artifactory, jfrog-cli

Getting this error after installing Artifactory

```
artifactory.service - Artifactory service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/artifactory.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: protocol) since Mon 2023-02-13 14:14:06 UTC; 43s ago
  Process: 1469 ExecStart=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/bin/artifactoryManage.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 26760 (code=exited, status=143)
 
Feb 13 14:14:06 mbiazelkdynatrace systemd[1]: Failed to start Artifactory service.
Feb 13 14:14:06 mbiazelkdynatrace systemd[1]: Unit artifactory.service entered failed state.
Feb 13 14:14:06 mbiazelkdynatrace systemd[1]: artifactory.service failed.
[root@mbiazelkdynatrace run]# systemctl status artifactory.service
```

Please help figure out the issue; I've trying this for the last two weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to start for the first time, there may be an issue with ports where [the ports required for Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/System+Requirements) might already being used.

The above snippet does not reveal anything of the issue.
Can you try to perform the below steps.

1. Stop Artifactory from service.
2. Navigate to $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/app/bin (ideally /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/bin if you have not changed the default location)

   ./artifactoryctl start
3. Navigate to $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/log location
   tail the console.log that should reveal what is the issue.
   or artifactory-service.log should reveal the issue.

If nothing is found, share the error snippet from artifactory-service.log

Comment: Hi, I actually tried the installation multiple times, first time the service was running fine but i couldnt load the localhost:8082 so thought the setup was wrong tried to remove the files and started from scratch but when i was removing the configuration for the first time it entered failed start. Tried the installation with the different version now and the installation completed but unable to start the service and seeing the same error that was encountered while removing the config for the first time

Comment: <2> Like you mentioned I tried to stop the service and start ./artifactoryctl got this error

Comment: [root@mbiazelkdynatrace bin]# ./artifactoryctl start
Job for artifactory.service failed. See "systemctl status artifactory.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: tail -10 console.log
2023-02-14T01:51:13.708Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryManage.sh:69       ] [main] - Artifactory Tomcat already started
2023-02-14T01:52:14.045Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:582       ] [main] - Resolved .shared.user (artifactory) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
console.log only shows the above logs and I dont see any issue with that

Comment: when i checked "journalctl -xe" i got this "Can't open PID file /var/run/artifactory.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Feb 14 01:57:16 mbiazelkdynatrace systemd[1]: Failed to start Artifactory service." There is no run folder within var, run/artifactory.pid is present in app instead i.e app/run/artifactory.pid

Comment: Now I see a new failure : Using default router's certificate and private key
artifactoryManage.sh[8609]: Stopping router...
artifactoryManage.sh[8609]: router is running (PID: 32489). Stopping it...
artifactoryManage.sh[8609]: /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/router/bin/router.sh: line 264: kill: (32489) - No such process
artifactoryManage.sh[8609]: ERROR: Stopping router failed

Comment: kill all the java processes that are running. 
> ps -ef | grep java
> kill -9 process id. 
now try to start artifactory from bin folder. 
These snippets aren't sufficient. Can you navigate to $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/log/tomcat/tomcat-localhost-yyyy-mm-dd.log to see if there is any useful information. 
Also, visit $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/log/access-service.log

Comment: I tried to erase the setup and reinstalled it from scratch, started ./artifactory start and ./artifactory check to see the status. Everything looked fine but when i ran systemctl status artifactory, it showed the error from previous setup. I ran systemctl stop artifactory then ran ./artifactoryctl start now partially ran fine then went in loop ....

Comment: JF_ROUTER_TOPOLOGY_LOCAL_REQUIREDSERVICETYPES : jfrt,jfac,jfmd,jffe,jfob,jfint
JF_SHARED_NODE_NAME                 : mbiazelkdynatrace
JF_SHARED_NODE_IP                   : 10.129.50.184
JF_SYSTEM_YAML                      : /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
JF_SHARED_NODE_ID                   : mbiazelkdynatrace
Using default router's certificate and private key
Starting router...
router is already running (PID: 9911)
Restarting router...
Using default router's certificate and private key
Stopping router...
router is running (PID: 9911). Stopping it...
router stopped

Comment: Not sure what am i missing here, i have tried almost everything in the past few days

Comment: Checked console.log i saw 1 warning message "[WARN ] [2ebc4089dff09244] [o.a.p.s.ProbesServiceImpl:261 ] [art-exec-5          ] - Readiness Access service ping test failed with the following error: Access service is unavailable: Unable to connect to Access server: Read timed out

Comment: Another error : [jfrt ] [ERROR] [                ] [j.a.c.g.GrpcStreamObserver:168] [scribe_1676441367796] - Could not resubscribe (platform config)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: call was cancelled
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:508)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.sendMessageInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:514)

Comment: When I ran artifactory as a process ./artifactoryctl start it ran without any issue but I cant load the ui in the browser. I have opened the firewall-cmd ports 8081 and 8082. Still it is not working

Comment: I would suggest reaching out to JFrog Support.